# Why the autofocus didn't work?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing a camera related app. Now I succeeded to capture camera preview. However, when I was trying to set autofocus to my app, it didn't work. I tried both AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus and AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus, neither of them worked. 
By the way, I tested on iPhone 6s.

my ViewController.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    AVCaptureSession *cameraCaptureSession;
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *cameraPreviewLayer;
}

- (void) initializeCaptureSession;

@end
```

my ViewController.m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a    nib.
    [self initializeCaptureSession];

}

- (void) initializeCaptureSession
{
    //Attempt to initialize AVCaptureDevice with back camera
    NSArray *videoDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = nil;
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in videoDevices){
        if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack)
        {
            captureDevice = device;
            break;
        }
    }

    //If camera is accessible by capture session
    if (captureDevice)
    {
        if ([captureDevice isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus]){
            NSError *error;
            if ([captureDevice lockForConfiguration:&error]){
                [captureDevice setFocusPointOfInterest:CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f)];
                [captureDevice setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus];
                [captureDevice unlockForConfiguration];
            }else{
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            }
        }


        //Allocate camera capture session
        cameraCaptureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
        cameraCaptureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

        //Configure capture session input
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoIn = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:nil];
        [cameraCaptureSession addInput:videoIn];

        //Configure capture session output
        AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *videoOut = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
        [videoOut setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES];
        [cameraCaptureSession addOutput:videoOut];


        //Bind preview layer to capture session data
        cameraPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:cameraCaptureSession];
        CGRect layerRect = self.view.bounds;
        cameraPreviewLayer.bounds = self.view.bounds;
        cameraPreviewLayer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect), CGRectGetMidY(layerRect));
        cameraPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

        //Add preview layer to UIView layer
        [self.view.layer addSublayer:cameraPreviewLayer];

        //Begin camera capture
        [cameraCaptureSession startRunning];

    }

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    [cameraCaptureSession stopRunning];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AVCaptureSession *captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc]init];
previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:captureSession];
previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
NSError *err = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoIn = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error: &err];
if (err == nil){
    if ([captureSession canAddInput:videoIn]){
        [captureSession addInput:videoIn];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Failed to add video input");
    }
}else{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",err);
}
[captureSession startRunning];

previewLayer.frame = [self.view bounds];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
```

I am not sure what happened but if I used the code above the camera can give me a clear preview.

Answer (score 0):

here is of my code on swift, its tested on my iPhone 5s and working only on back camera, i don't know how about iPhone 6s

```
    `if let device = captureDevice {
        try! device.lockForConfiguration()
        if device.isFocusModeSupported(.autoFocus) {
            device.focusMode = .autoFocus
        }
        device.unlockForConfiguration()
     }`
```

i think you need to remove

```
[captureDevice setFocusPointOfInterest:CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f)];
```

Comment: Actually even if I remove that it still didn't work. And that line I got from one of stackoverflow answers, I can't find the thread currently. Whatever, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this:

```
 if ([self.session canAddInput:videoDeviceInput]) {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification object:currentDevice];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(subjectAreaDidChange:) name:AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification object:videoDevice];

        [self.session addInput:videoDeviceInput];
        self.videoDeviceInput = videoDeviceInput;
    }
```

Then:

```
- (void)subjectAreaDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGPoint devicePoint = CGPointMake( 0.5, 0.5 );
    [self focusWithMode:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus exposeWithMode:AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure atDevicePoint:devicePoint monitorSubjectAreaChange:NO];
}
```

And Then:

```
- (void)focusWithMode:(AVCaptureFocusMode)focusMode exposeWithMode:(AVCaptureExposureMode)exposureMode atDevicePoint:(CGPoint)point monitorSubjectAreaChange:(BOOL)monitorSubjectAreaChange
{
    dispatch_async( self.sessionQueue, ^{
        AVCaptureDevice *device = self.videoDeviceInput.device;
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ( [device lockForConfiguration:&error] ) {
            // Setting (focus/exposure)PointOfInterest alone does not initiate a (focus/exposure) operation.
            // Call -set(Focus/Exposure)Mode: to apply the new point of interest.
            if ( device.isFocusPointOfInterestSupported && [device isFocusModeSupported:focusMode] ) {
                device.focusPointOfInterest = point;
                device.focusMode = focusMode;
            }

            if ( device.isExposurePointOfInterestSupported && [device isExposureModeSupported:exposureMode] ) {
                device.exposurePointOfInterest = point;
                device.exposureMode = exposureMode;
            }

            device.subjectAreaChangeMonitoringEnabled = monitorSubjectAreaChange;
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
        else {
            NSLog( @"Could not lock device for configuration: %@", error );
        }
    } );
}
```

This was a code from a project I worked. Feel free to ask if you have any doubt.